# QListView implement drag and drop internal move removes the items rather than moving them around

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListView and want to implement drag and drop to let user move items around in the list to his/her desired order. My code excerpt is

```
  ui.lstViewBodyFiles->setDragEnabled(true);
  ui.lstViewBodyFiles->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
  ui.lstViewBodyFiles->setAcceptDrops(true);
  ui.lstViewBodyFiles->setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
  ui.lstViewBodyFiles->setDragDropMode( QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
```

the above code removes the items rather than moving them internally.

Qt 5.3.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: Related: https://forum.qt.io/topic/36433/qlistview-scrolls-up-on-list-item-drop/3

Answer (score 0):

You need to setDragDropOverwriteMode(false).